# How to hide div with numeric value

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to hide a div after succesfull submission of a form.

The problem is that that every div has an unique ID, like

```
  <div id="ticket_1324">
   ...
  </div>
```

To process the form I have this (working) function:

```
        <script>
          function dosubmit(id){
                var data = $('form').serialize();
                $.post('url', $("form").serialize(), function(data) {
                $('#ticket_'.id).fadeOut('fast');

});
};
         </script>
```

For some reason the '#ticket_'.id does not reflect: ticket_1324.

How can I solve this?

I have a second question:

when the form has a value like last=1 then after processing I need a page reload.

```
<input type="hidden" name="last" value="1" />
```

The data is serialized. How can I get the value of last? data.last does not work ...

How can I do that?

Comment: Dot (`.`) is the string concatenation operator in PHP. In Javascript it's `+`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

replace `.` with `+`

```
$('#ticket_'+id).fadeOut('fast');
```

Answer to your second question

You can get the value of your input this way

```
if($("input[name='last']").val() == 1){
    // do your processing
 }
```